# Separating the "host" and "external" (loadbalancer) networks in Kubernetes?

Tags: networking, centos7, linux-networking, kubernetes

Because I like to have things separate (security concern) I’m currently experimenting to see if I can have completely separate networks in Kubernetes for the “hosts” network and the “external” network where I want [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) to manage the traffic.

As an experimentation setup I now have two separate vlans and a VMware virtual machine which simply sees two normal network interfaces.

On that VM I have installed CentOS 7, Kubernetes 1.17, Calico 3.13.1 and MetalLB 0.8.2

I expect that I do not need to give the node an IP address on the “external” interface because in the [MetalLB manual](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/#layer-2-configuration) I read

> Layer 2 mode does not require the IPs to be bound to the network
>   interfaces of your worker nodes. It works by responding to ARP
>   requests on your local network directly, to give the machine’s MAC
>   address to clients.

This is nice because that way the node is effectively unreachable from the "external" network.

For my testing I have configured metallb to manage a range of IP on both networks (just for testing)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 10.123.123.100-10.123.123.199
      - 10.123.45.100-10.123.45.199
```

On the VM I give the host interface an ip address (DHCP) and that all works fine.
I do not give the “external” interface an IP/routing/… yet I have made sure it is “up”.

So I see this (ens192 = hosts, ens224 = external)

```
[root@node1 ~]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:ca:06:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.123.123.6/24 brd 10.123.123.255 scope global dynamic ens192
       valid_lft 75786sec preferred_lft 75786sec
3: ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:ca:06:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:dc:25:87:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

(and a lot of cali* interfaces)

```
[root@node1 ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.123.123.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens192
10.123.123.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens192
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.135.192 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 *
192.168.135.242 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 calia47abf08c66
…
```

For testing I have [a simple web app](https://yauaa.basjes.nl/README-WebServlet.html) and I’ve attached two K8s services to it: One with a loadBalancerIP on the “host” network and one on the “external” network.

```
[root@node1 ~]# kubectl -n yauaa get all
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/yauaa-7d7bffd9fc-tdhg9   1/1     Running   5          2d6h

NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
service/yauaa       LoadBalancer   10.104.33.179   10.123.123.100   80:31908/TCP   2d3h
service/yauaa-pub   LoadBalancer   10.105.4.161    10.123.45.100    80:30695/TCP   2d7h

NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/yauaa   1/1     1            1           2d7h

NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/yauaa-7d7bffd9fc   1         1         1       2d6h
```

Running locally on the k8s node itself I can do a curl to either IP and both respond immediately. So the binding provided by metallb to the services seems to work.

Now on my firewall (a linux device) I can do a curl to either IP, the “host” one responds, the “external” one does not. I do see that the correct IP-MAC mapping is present in the arp table of this firewall. Yet I do not get a response.

```
# arp -a | fgrep 10.123
node1.k8s.basjes.nl (10.123.123.6) at 00:0c:29:ca:06:13 [ether] on eth1.2222
? (10.123.123.100) at 00:0c:29:ca:06:13 [ether] on eth1.2222
? (10.123.45.100) at 00:0c:29:ca:06:1d [ether] on eth1.2345
```

I have tried setting the ens224 in promiscuous mode, I have tried adding a routing entry to the gateway for that interface but that did not help.

I did manage to get it running by actually giving this ens224 interface an IP address but that is what I prefer not to have and which (if I understand the documentation correctly) is not needed.

Apparently I’m doing something wrong.

What is the correct way to configure this?

Comment: What error is shown when you try to access the external IP? Can you post output of `kubectl get service` ?

Comment: When accessing the external IP within the k8s node I get an immediate response, when on my firewall (or any other system) I get a timeout. I've updated my question to include the output from kubectl.

Comment: Just pointing out the obvious, metallb requires kubermetes 1.13 and higher. It is not compatible with your kubernetes 1.7. That is not likely your problem though.

Comment: I made a typo. I have 1.17 (i.e. the latest)

Comment: I tried to reproduce your use case, and actually hit the same issue when one of NICs (meant for external network) has no IP address currently assigned. You might find interesting the fact that ARP request/response can be still seen in Speaker's logs when probing the K8S Service with ExternalIP from outside of cluster.

Comment: Yes, this matches my observation that in the arp cache of my firewall these ip-mac combinations are correctly recorded.